# What does $\forall x \exists y(x + y = 0)$ mean?

Tags: logic

What does $\forall x \exists y(x + y = 0)$ mean?

Does it mean "For all x there exists a y for which x + y equals zero"?

Thanks.

Comment: tip: You may accept an answer that you find helpful (you can accept one answer per question) by clicking on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it does.

In plainer, more succinct words, it means that "every number has an additive inverse".

Comment: Also, be absolutely sure not to confuse this with $\exists y \forall x (x + y = 0)$. The two statements are subtly different, in that in the first one, the $y$ can be different for each $x$, but in the second one, the *same* $y$ needs to work for *all* $x$.

Comment: Think of it as the "such that" *always immediately* following the variable that the $\exists$ refers to. "For all $x$ there exists a $y$ such that $x + y = 0$" is not the same as "There exists a $y$ such that for all $x$, $x + y = 0$". And "There exists a $y$ for all $x$ such that $x + y = 0$" would not be a valid transcription of a first-order logic sentence (even though syntactically it should be equivalent to $\forall x \exists y (x + y = 0)$).

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you're correct.

However, it seems a bit clearer if it is written (as suggested in the comments) as

$$\forall x:\exists y : (x + y = 0)$$

Comment: I find this notation unwieldy as well, though I have seen it in Rosen's "Discrete Mathematics and Applications" book.

Comment: In statements in first-order logic, there is no "such that". It's implicit in the $\exists$.

Comment: Such that is denoted by $\mid$, isn't it?

Comment: @Joe good to know, thanks.

Comment: I think you just pinged yourself. :P

Comment: @saadtaame: No. Set builder notation $\{\cdots\mid\cdots\}$ is _one symbol_ whose components cannot be picked out and used separately from the context they are defined to mean something in. (Set brackets are _separately_ defined to mean something else when there is no $\mid$).

Comment: If at all I'd prefer the colon as a separator,$\forall x\colon\exists y\colon x+y=0$ , but only because its general spacing introduces legibility

Comment: We used a lower dot in CS 245 ourselves. Like this: $\forall x . \exists y . x + y = 0$

Comment: @JoeZeng: Using a dot there seems to be peculiar to (or at least a lot more common in) computer science. This dot is a common syntactic motif for variable binders in formal calculi used in CS, probably influenced above all by the $\lambda$-calculus.

Comment: @HenningMakholm my undergraduate discrete math book uses $|$ for "such that". In general I think $|$ can be a valid alternative to $:$ for "such that". (See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) which lists both for "such that")